# Catch Axios exception in Vuex store and throw it to Vue.js method

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

How to catch **axios** exceptions in **vuex** store and throw it to **vue.js** method ? My goal is to get this exception to be able to reset computed values bound to `input` using `this.$forceUpdate()`.

In my method, I have this:

```
methods: {
    mymet: _.debounce(
        function(table, id, key, event) {
            const value = event.target.value;
            this.$store.dispatch('UPDATE_TRANSACTIONS_ITEM', { table, id, key, value }).then(response => {
                event.target.classList.remove("is-invalid")
                event.target.classList.add("is-valid")
            }, error => {
                console.error("Got nothing from server. Prompt user to check internet connection and try again")
                this.$forceUpdate();
            })
        }, 500
    )
}
```

In my vuex store, I have this:

```
const actions = {
    UPDATE_TRANSACTIONS_ITEM ({ commit }, data) {
        let company = {
            [data.key]: data.value
        }
        axios.put(`/api/companies/${data.id}`, { company }).then( function ( response ) {
            commit('SET_TRANSACTIONS_ITEM_UPDATE', { profile: data })
        }).catch(function (error) {
            throw error
        })
    }
}

const mutations = {
    SET_TRANSACTIONS_ITEM_UPDATE (state, { profile }) {
        state.company_data[profile.key] = profile.value
    },
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the actual action function asynchronous.

If you have the ability to use [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), you can just await the `axios` call, and let the error bubble up (no need to throw anything in the action itself):

```
const actions = {
  async UPDATE_TRANSACTIONS_ITEM ({ commit }, data) {
    let company = {[data.key]: data.value};
    await axios.put(`/api/companies/${data.id}`, { company }).then(() => {
      commit('SET_TRANSACTIONS_ITEM_UPDATE', { profile: data })
    });
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and catch the error and pass it to the `reject` handler:

```
const actions = {
  UPDATE_TRANSACTIONS_ITEM ({ commit }, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let company = {[data.key]: data.value};
      axios.put(`/api/companies/${data.id}`, { company }).then(() => {
        commit('SET_TRANSACTIONS_ITEM_UPDATE', { profile: data });
        resolve();
      }, (error) => reject(error));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this would need a try/catch block, no?

Comment: You could add a try catch block to the async example to handle the error within the action and then throw the error, but its not necessary if you just want the error to bubble up.

Comment: Aha I see, so it will be bubbled up by default if you don't call it in the deeper methods, right?